# In AngularJS, why would a directive require itself?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn from the angular-ui code. I see that the `btnRadio` directive requires itself. I understand that directives may `require` controllers and then access them as an array in the fourth parameter of the `link` function. I don't understand why a directive would require itself though.

```
.directive('btnRadio', function () {
  return {
    require: ['btnRadio', 'ngModel'],
    controller: 'ButtonsController',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var buttonsCtrl = ctrls[0], ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];
      ...
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/buttons.js#L15

This is just requiring its own controller, right? What is the purpose of this, or what problem is it solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of that application is very odd to me. It seems that they could better define it like this:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap')
  .controller('ButtonsController', function($scope, buttonConfig) {
    $scope.activeClass = buttonConfig.activeClass || 'active';
    $scope.toggleEvent = buttonConfig.toggleEvent || 'click';
  })
  .directive('btnRadio', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller: 'ButtonsController',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        // These are now available here in the link function
        scope.activeClass;
        scope.toggleEvent;
        // ... other functionality
      }
    }
  });
```

However, @Jeff is right. They do it so that they will have access to the `ButtonsController`. If you look further down in the code, they're just using it to access the `activeClass` and `toggleEvent` attributes.

The only reason I can think for doing it the way that it currently is done would be to avoid generating an isolate scope on the directive. An isolate scope might interfere with code that is external  to this library.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's to retrieve the controller inside the link function.

Comment: I see that too, but couldn't you just DI the controller from the directive? `.directive('btnRadio', function(ButtonsController){});`

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe Have you tried that? I don't think its possible.. http://jsfiddle.net/E6EfQ/

Comment: Oops, you're right. When I've needed something similar I've had to pull shared methods into services and share the service between the controller and directive. Maybe this is related.